# How to generate findbugs reports using gradle script?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, checkstyle, findbugs

I am trying to generate reports using findbugs plugin for that i wrote below mentioned gradle script.I am setting the destination folder for reports but respective folder not get generated.So, how to solve this issue.

I can able to generate reports manually by using export button but i want generate from the gradle script.

Is it possible to generate reports from gradle script?

my gradle version - 2.2.1

```
task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = true
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    classes = files("${project.buildDir}/findbugs")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs/findbugs.xml"
            xml.withMessages true
        }
    }
    classpath = files()
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to get to run findbugs with the newest gradle with the following gradle script snippet:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

task customFindbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = true
    effort = "default"
    reportLevel = "medium"
    classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes")
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.rootDir/config/findbugs/exclude.xml")

    source = fileTree('src/main/java/')
    classpath = files()
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        xml.withMessages = true
        html.enabled = !xml.isEnabled()
        xml.destination "$project.buildDir/outputs/findbugs/findbugs-output.xml"
        html.destination "$project.buildDir/outputs/findbugs/findbugs-output.html"
    }
}
// UPDATE: renamed the task to customFindbugs and made it automatically be called when build is called
build.dependsOn customFindbugs
```

My exclude.xml looks like the following:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
       <Class name="~.*R\$.*"/>
    </Match>
    <Match>
        <Class name="~.*Manifest\$.*"/>
    </Match>
    <Match>
        <Class name="~.*_\$.*"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

whereas the last check is used to omit classes generated by AndroidAnnotations and you most likely won't use this check...

After that I'm able to run the task by

```
./gradlew customFindbugs
```

or since the update of my code just by

```
./gradlew build
```

Comment: your code is working fine, How to write a task in build.gradle for JavaDoc generation?

Comment: Sorry, Boopathi, I don't know a quick answer for that. I would also have to do some research. I always use Android Studio (Tools --> Generate Javadoc).
By the way, I updated my code so that you are able to implicitly call the task when you call ./gradlew build

Comment: Does `build.dependsOn customFindbugs` necessary? I mean `./gradlew build` triggers the `check` task and that depends on Findbugs.

Comment: @Hesam in my case nothing gets generated if I don't make it explicitly depend on build.

Comment: i am getting error:cannot read file from findbugs excludeFilter i.e exclude.xml

Comment: @abh22ishek put it outside the android tag. I put it into an extra checks.gradle file and include it via "apply from './checks.gradle'" above the android tag. The path to the exclude doesn't seem to be correct then: either create a config folder in the root of your project or change the path I use